# Infinite Electrical Field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors, polarization

If we place conductor (let say a cube) in a constant electric field, it would make charges on different sides of the conductor, where these charges also make their electric field on each point outside the conductor.

Electric field created by the pole too far from that specific point will be opposite direction to that original constant field, and Electrical field created by the nearest pole will result same-directed electric field. Overall, net electric field will be same-directed like original, constant electric field was.

So, placing a conductor will increase Electric fields outside. What if we place many conductors next to each other, would I get as much electric field (at least its x-component value) as I want?

It sounds like an 'abuse', and any help analyzing this model better would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The electric field near the conductor is not an uniform field. You cannot just add the field before inserting the conductor to the field of the induced charges. This is the problem with conductors.

Comment: Yes, Electric field is not an uniform field after I insert conductor in it, but for simplicity, we can talk about only x-projected electric field, could not we? and what I say, is that field on x-axis will be increased, am I right?

Comment: Not, it does not have to increase. The distorsion of the field is in both components, not just along the y axis.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a cube, use an infinite slab (so the transverse coordinates don't matter). We have:

$$ E(x) = E_0 $$

Then $\nabla \vec E \rightarrow dE/dx$, so with no conductor:

$$ \frac{dE}{dx} = \frac 1 {\epsilon_0}\rho(x)= 0$$

which of course is solved by $E(x)=E_0$.

Now place a conductor with a surface at $x=0$. A charge is induced:

$$ \rho(x) = E_0 \epsilon_0 \delta(x)$$

and the field that has that derivative (divided by permittivity) is given in terms of the Heavyside step function:

$$ E(x) ={E_0}  \big(1-H(x)\big) $$

or, in terms of regions:

$$ E(x) = E_0\ \ \ \ \ (x<0)$$
$$ E(x) = 0\ \ \ \ \ (x>0)$$

That is: the field outside the conductor does not increase. Loosely, moving from left to right, the constant field lines meet a surface charge density that exactly cancels them.

Another way to look at is that positive charges source field lines, and negative charge sink them. The question implies the negative charges in the conductor increase the field outside the conductor, which is understandable given $E=-\Delta V/\Delta x$ and $\Delta x$ is smaller, but it's a misconception: $\Delta V$ is also smaller, as it's the integral along field lines, and the field lines disappear at the surface of negative charge.